# Resizing array when elements are more than 1/2 of his size

Tags: java, arrays, hashtable

I'm trying to resizing my array when N, the number of elements, is greater than m/2, m is the initial size of the array, but it doesn't work and I don't understand why. This array should work like an hashtable, so I have an hashing function before every insert, and after the resizing I want to insert again every element with a new hashing (m value changed). This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at JumpHashing.resize(JumpHashing.java:55)
    at JumpHashing.put(JumpHashing.java:50)
    at JumpHashing.hashing(JumpHashing.java:40)
    at JumpHashing.resize(JumpHashing.java:61)
    at JumpHashing.put(JumpHashing.java:50)
    at JumpHashing.hashing(JumpHashing.java:40)
    at JumpHashing.resize(JumpHashing.java:61)
    at JumpHashing.put(JumpHashing.java:50)
    at JumpHashing.hashing(JumpHashing.java:40)
    at JumpHashing.resize(JumpHashing.java:61)
    at JumpHashing.put(JumpHashing.java:50)
    at JumpHashing.hashing(JumpHashing.java:40)
    at JumpHashing.resize(JumpHashing.java:61)
    at JumpHashing.put(JumpHashing.java:50)
    at JumpHashing.hashing(JumpHashing.java:40)
    at JumpHashing.resize(JumpHashing.java:61)
    at JumpHashing.put(JumpHashing.java:50)
    at JumpHashing.hashing(JumpHashing.java:40)
    at JumpHashing.resize(JumpHashing.java:61)
    at JumpHashing.put(JumpHashing.java:50)
    at JumpHashing.hashing(JumpHashing.java:40)
    at JumpHashing.resize(JumpHashing.java:61)
    at JumpHashing.put(JumpHashing.java:50)
    at JumpHashing.hashing(JumpHashing.java:40)
    at JumpHashing.resize(JumpHashing.java:61)
    at JumpHashing.put(JumpHashing.java:50)
    at JumpHashing.hashing(JumpHashing.java:40)
    at JumpHashing.resize(JumpHashing.java:61)
    at JumpHashing.put(JumpHashing.java:50)
    at JumpHashing.hashing(JumpHashing.java:40)
    at JumpHashing.resize(JumpHashing.java:61)
    at JumpHashing.put(JumpHashing.java:50)
```

The problem is clearly the resizing, without it (with less than 23 elements) it works.

Inititial size of m is 23, this is the actual code (Class "In" for reading file from algs4):

```
public class JumpHashing{
    private int m;
    private int[] hashTable; 
    private static int id;
    private int N;

    public JumpHashing(){
        m = 23;
        hashTable = new int[m];
        N = 0;
    }

    public void hashing(int value) {
            int key = (value*11)%m;
            put(key, value);
    }

    public void put(int key, int value) {
        if(N <m/2) {
            hashTable[key] = value;
            N++;
        } else {
            m=m*2;
            N=0;
            resize(m);
        }
    }

    public void resize(int m) { 
        int[] temp = new int[m];
        for(int i=0; i<hashTable.length; i++) {
            temp[i] = hashTable[i];
        }
        hashTable = new int[m];
        for(int i=0; i<temp.length; i++) {
            hashing(temp[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JumpHashing hashT1 = new JumpHashing();

        In file = new In("random.txt");
        while(file.hasNextLine()) {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(file.readLine());
            hashT1.hashing(value);
        }   
        for(int j=0; j<hashT1.hashTable.length; j++) {
            StdOut.println("Key: "+j+" Value: "+hashT1.hashTable[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe shrink the code (like only the parts that don't work)? Also, please give the line in which the error appears!

Comment: You’re creating a loop of methods here, so you get the stackoverflow. I didn't check in detail, but it looks like hashing calls put, that calls resize and that calls hashing.

Comment: `if(N <m/2) {`, variable names should start with a lowercase letter and be more descriptive than just a single character for better readability.

Comment: @AyushGarg edited with the errors, but that's the problem, it's just about the 3 methods put, hashing and resize, like an infinite loop

Comment: @TomStroemer yes, but I really don't understand how to solve that right now, it's like the m value never stop growing, but without the resize it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You end up repeatedly calling `resize` until memory is used up. The problem is in this function:

```
    public void resize(int m) { 
        int[] temp = new int[m];  // <-- this is the new double-size of m
        for(int i=0; i<hashTable.length; i++) {
            temp[i] = hashTable[i];
        }
        hashTable = new int[m];
        for(int i=0; i<temp.length; i++) {  // <-- here we go too far
            hashing(temp[i]);
        }
    }
```

Your second loop goes through the full new 'm' size array, not the original m/2 size array. Half way plus one through the loop your `N` will be greater than `m/2` again and it will call resize every time that happens.

Here's what you should have in that function:

```
public void resize(int m) {
    int[] oldHash = hashTable;
    hashTable = new int[m];
    for(int i=0; i<oldHash.length; i++) {
        if (oldHash[i] != 0) {     // <-- don't hash empty slots
            hashing(oldHash[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This also improves performance because you loop through just once and no more than m/2 times.

Comment: Thanks! But it still goes on Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at JumpHashing.resize(JumpHashing.java:34)
 at JumpHashing.put(JumpHashing.java:28)
 at JumpHashing.hashing(JumpHashing.java:18)
 at JumpHashing.main(JumpHashing.java:46)

Comment: right - I had to add the new if-statement to avoid hashing empty slots too. See the edited answer.